# Solution to equation won't display? (no errors being reported on my end)

Tags: java, android

So I managed to take 4 different activities involving 4 variables and wrote them in this kind of format:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_step1);

    Button c = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.continue1); 
    final EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enterscore);
    input.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


    public void onClick(View v) {
        String score1 = input.getText().toString();
            Double.parseDouble(score1);
        { Intent myintent = (new Intent(step1.this,step2.class));
        myintent.putExtra("SCORE1",score1);
        startActivity(myintent);

        }
```

On my final activity the one that's suppose to display the solution I have coded the following:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_answer);
    }


public void solutionf(View v) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras!=null){
        double score1 = extras.getDouble("SCORE1");
        double score2 = extras.getDouble("SCOREF");
        double l2 = extras.getDouble("L2");
        double l3= extras.getDouble("L3");
        double solution= (((score2-score1)/l2)*l3);
            String resultString = "Result:" +solution;
            TextView resultText= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.solution);
        resultText.setText(resultstring);
        }
    }
}
```

Why won't the final solution display? I've checked over to make sure everything matches up in terms of the doubles that are set in the activities.  Could it be I didn't properly bring the variables over from the previous activities through error on my code?

Any help to getting the solution to show would be appreciated!

Comment: how have u called your solutionf() ?

Comment: solution() I made a typo and is the actual name and I set it to view since I wanted the answer output to go to textview where the String is the solution.  (sorry if it's wrong or seems stupid, I'm very new at programming)

Answer (score 0):

Unless a part of your code is missing, solution() is never called.
Add a call to this function in onCreate of your second activity, it should help.

Comment: I fixed it after checking my xml page and realized something goofed up (spelling).  Now I think eclipse is glitching on me or something.  For some reason today when I opened eclipse, it told me that "the operator "*" is undefined type(s) double,string where double solution is.  I just cleaning and refreshing, opening and closing eclipse... still the same error.  I'll update on this later.  Thanks again for your help!